# python subprocess module stuck while executing a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I am trying to learn to code using python on my own but I ran into a problem.

I am using python's subprocess module to execute a .bat file, but the process seems to get stuck at the bat file. The python code currently looks like this:

```
import  getpass
username = getpass.getuser()
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("hidefolder.bat", cwd=r"C:\Users\%s\Desktop" % username)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
import sys
sys.exit()
```

And the .bat file looks like this:

```
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HiddenFolder\" (
    attrib -s -h "HiddenFolder"
    rename "HiddenFolder" "Projects"
    exit
    )
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Projects\" (
    rename "Projects" "HiddenFolder"
    attrib +s +h "HiddenFolder"
    exit
    )
if not exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HiddenFolder\" (
    mkdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HiddenFolder\"
    )
exit
```

Is there a way to kill the child process even if the python script is waiting for the child process to be terminated before continuing? Or is the problem in the child process to start with?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `subprocess.PIPE` for `stdout` and `stderr`, or else they can't be fetched through `Popen.communicate`, and is the reason why your process is stuck.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import  getpass
username = getpass.getuser()
p = Popen("hidefolder.bat", cwd=r"C:\Users\%s\Desktop" % username, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a new programmer but i could solve my problem writting below code.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'ProcurementSoftwareRun.bat'])
print ('Software run successful')
```

My bat file was like:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /c start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\UserName\ERPModule\PROCUREMENT.exe
exit
```